# Which Google analytics cocoapods pod to use

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, firebase, cocoapods

From the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=objc) Google suggest to use the submodule from the Google pod

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

But if you search on [cocoapods.org](http://cocoapods.org/) there is separate pod maintained by Google as well, called [GoogleAnalytics](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics)

As of this writing, in the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=objc) they also have a note, which make things more confusing:

> Note: Beginning with version 3.16 of the Google Analytics for iOS SDK, Xcode 7.3 or higher is required.

Current version of [Google pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Google) is 3.0.3

Current version of [GoogleAnalytics pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics) is 3.16.0

From the [.podspec of Google](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/3.0.3/Google.podspec.json) we can see that it has as [dependency 'GoogleAnalytics'](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/3.0.3/Google.podspec.json#L78) but also '[FirebaseAnalytics](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Google/3.0.3/Google.podspec.json#L59)'

1. Is [GoogleAnalytics](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics) not intended for direct use (like [GoogleUtilities](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleUtilities))?
2. Why Google pod (version 3.0.3) is using 'FirebaseAnalytics' pod and how does this affect the Google Analytics dashboard?

Comment: It is no longer the case that the documentation recommends using `Google/Analytics`. It now tells you to use `GoogleAnalytics`, however it gives you the wrong import statement.

Answer (score 2):

the `Google/Analytics` pod is the one that should be used when implementing Google Analytics in your iOS app.  You are correct in that the `GoogleAnalytics` pod is not meant for direct use; we'll be updating the pod description.

Comment: It doesn't look like this answer is correct anymore. The current documentation tells you to use `GoogleAnalytics` but gives the wrong import statement for that pod. It is still giving the import statement that should be used with the now deprecated `Google/Analytics` pod.